# Do the values over 0.5 mean my model classified the data as a "1" label and vice versa?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, long-short-term-memory, keras, sigmoid

I am doing binary classification using an LSTM and my output layer is 1 neuron with a sigmoid function. My labels are either 0 or 1.

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64,activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(PERCENT_DATA,1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
opt = SGD(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

An example of the outputs is

```
array([[0.9854203 ],
       [0.94532275],
       [0.946043  ],
       [0.5212766 ],
       [0.45969874],
       [0.53517556],
       [0.88838553],
       [0.05345109],
       [0.06565621],
       [0.5552153 ],
       [0.07443756],
       [0.62434113]])
```

Do the values over 0.5 mean my model classified the data as a "1" label and vice versa? Or should I try to find an optimal threshold from these values that will result in the highest accuracy? Or do these values mean something else like the confidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the values over 0.5 mean the output should have "1" label.

As I know with Keras you cannot set the optimal threshold, but you still can use the trick if you want, for example, the expected threshold is `0.8`, you can minus the output then clamp the minimum cap of it to 0. {out = max(out-(thresh-0.5), 0)}

However, finding the optimal threshold for a model is not recommended in a real project since it may adapt to your validation set only, try to work more with data. I am not familiar with NLP data, but I am sure there are some methods to make data more variant. Label smoothing (as [Keras documents](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy)) can be a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found that 0.5 isn't a good threshold for predictions, and have calculated a better one by testing other decimal numbers. Would this work?

Comment: maybe in this case. you can try it, by the method I said above